# Postgres View with content from another Databaseserver

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, view

Is it somehow possible to create a view on a Postgres database which gets its original data from a table of a SQL Server database on another server?

I want to have the data from a table of the SQL Server database on server A inside a table on my Postgres database on server B, but I can't use export import, also no scripted solution because I need them nearly realtime.

Comment: There is a foreign data wrapper for SQL Server - but I don't know how well that works: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FDW and it currently only runs on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [FDW](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers)<sup>[1](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers)</sup> to connection on your MSSQL database and get your data. A FDW expose a remote service (a database, webservice, api, etc) like a table for read and write.

For MSSQL, the [`tds_fdw`](http://pgxn.org/dist/tds_fdw/)<sup>[2](http://pgxn.org/dist/tds_fdw/)</sup>can do the trick.

Let me know if you need a example or more details how the FDW work.

References:

1. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers
2. http://pgxn.org/dist/tds_fdw/

Comment: Thanks i tried it but it seem to not work - on the last part - import schema - i get the following Error.  - DB-Library error: DB #: 4060, DB Msg: General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server, OS #: -1, OS Msg: , Level: 11

Comment: and what says the mssql log?

Comment: You might take a look as well to connecting to MS SQL with a FDW that uses ODBC. If on windows, check http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/372-ODBC-FDW-now-supports-9.5-and-9.6.html. If on Linux/(and probably OS X), check https://github.com/CartoDB/odbc_fdw. The "native" FDW is marked with "Status: Unstable". Haven't found any mention for odbc_fdw. Check also: [ODBC Foreign Data wrapper to query SQL Server on Windows](http://www.postgresonline.com/article_pfriendly/249.html)

Comment: @SebastianWebber it worked with the lastest github branch and by importing the whole Schema (i first tried to make my own foreign table since i only need two of those 45 tables) - only point which isn't working as expected now is that if a original cell value contains a ä/ö/ü i get an empty cell in the foreign table and also the performance is really slow - that way it isn't working for what i wanna use it - i guess i just use connections to multiple Servers from the Program Side by now thanks anyway